# What is the right way to consume third party API using laravel 10

Tags: php, laravel, jwt, guzzle

the API use Jason web token to authenticate.
i'm using laravel 10

To login i send the user and password, then it return the user id and a the jwt token.

After that all  request that need to be made are supposed to be send somehow this token in the request.

I have worked with Laravel developing small applications using  mysql database , and letting it to manage as much as it can . but i haven found any project sample to follow in order to understand how should I approach it.

I have been playing with a basic Laravel project (without Jetstream), and Guzzle HTTP  to talk to the API, and i have been able to connect to the API a get the token, passing the token in the URI to try to do a request no another Controller/view ( which is not the idea but it's what i got so far.)

i have not yet idea how to handle the tokens on every user session and how to add it token to the header request.

any step-by-step guide /orientation will be appreciated. or project sample that can be disarm in order to get the idea about how to approach the project.

I connect to the api from the controller like this:

> In the AppServiceProvider.php a do the code injection

```
 public function register(): void
{
    $baseUrl = env('API_ENDPOINT');
    $this->app->singleton(Client::class, function($app) use ($baseUrl) 
    {
        return new Client(
                            [
                                 'base_uri' => $baseUrl
                                ,'verify' => false
                            ]
                         );
    });
```

> in a livewire component i manage the summit of the login form, but the token is expose in the URI

```
public function submit(Client $client)
{

   
    $this->validate([
        'user'=> 'required',
        'password'=> 'required',
    ]);

    $response = $client->request('GET', '/Login/'.$this->user.'/'.$this->password, [
                                                    'headers' =>['Accept'=>'application/json', ]
                                                ],);

   $ApiResponse = new ApiResponse();
   $ApiResponse = json_decode($response->getBody());
  
   if ( $ApiResponse->isSuccess== true) 
   {
    $user = new User();
    $user = $ApiResponse->resultObj;

    return  redirect(route( 'mainDashboard'
                        ,[
                            $user->id
                            ,$user->usrToken
                         ]));

   }else 
   {
    
        return  redirect( route('noAutorice'));


   }
}
```

Comment: Have you thought about returning the token after each request as a header (maybe sth. like `X-TOKEN`)? If you are using https in production (which you should), then the headers are also encrypted.